# Poor performance even through array of images is preloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a tiny widget which shows a 3D cube that rotates with the position of the mouse. I have achieved the effect with an if/else that looks at the browser window as 24 separate horizontal sections and displays the appropriate stage of rotation based on which section your mouse is touching. Works great locally, but performance when viewed online completely tanks. I thought preloading the images would make a difference, but it doesn't seem to help performance. My guess is that the images are still being called from the server even though they have been preloaded. The images are about 2kb in size each. Any ideas?

The complete code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Move your mouse, rotate the cube</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">    
      function rackEmUp()   {
      var i = 0;

      imageObj = new Image();

      images = new Array();
      images[0]="img/1.png"
      images[1]="img/2.png"
      images[2]="img/3.png"
      images[3]="img/4.png"
      images[4]="img/5.png"
      images[5]="img/6.png"
      images[6]="img/7.png"
      images[7]="img/8.png"
      images[8]="img/9.png"
      images[9]="img/10.png"
      images[10]="img/11.png"
      images[11]="img/12.png"
      images[12]="img/13.png"
      images[13]="img/14.png"
      images[14]="img/15.png"
      images[15]="img/16.png"
      images[16]="img/17.png"
      images[17]="img/18.png"
      images[18]="img/19.png"
      images[19]="img/20.png"
      images[20]="img/21.png"
      images[21]="img/22.png"
      images[22]="img/23.png"
      images[23]="img/24.png"

      for(i=0; i<=23; i++) {
           imageObj.src=images[i];
      }    
                                  }     
    rackEmUp();  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <img class="boxStage" src="img/1.png">

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).mousemove(function(event){
     var mloc = {
         x: event.pageX
     };

     if( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.04)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[0]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.08)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[1]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.12)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[2]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.16)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[3]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.20)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[4]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.24)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[5]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.28)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[6]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.32)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[7]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.36)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[8]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.40)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[9]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.44)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[10]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.48)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[11]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.52)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[12]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.56)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[13]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.60)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[14]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.64)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[15]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.68)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[16]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.72)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[17]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.76)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[18]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.80)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[19]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.84)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[20]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.88)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[21]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.92)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[22]);

     } else if

     ( 
         (mloc.x >= 0 && mloc.x <= $(document).width()*0.96)
     ){
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[23]);

     } else

     {
         $(".boxStage").attr("src", images[0]);
     };
        }); </script> </body> </html>
```

EDIT: Thanks everybody for your help - I wound up making one large banner image and changing the CSS background-position property in accordance with the position of the mouse.

Comment: where did you measure the performance

Comment: Tried running it from the machine I made it on, worked great. When I uploaded it to our web server and accessed it from there, the rotation was nowhere near smooth in comparison.

Comment: I would create 24 img tags in html with corresponding src's, and only show one of them in mousemove.

Comment: try adding the images in a div with display:none set to preload them, and fire your javascript on jQuery's `$(window).load()` event. I think your images might not be preloading, or the javascript is firing before they have preloaded - this way will make sure they get loaded before the script runs.

Comment: Try viewing it in a Webkit browser (Maybe Firebug can do this too?) and look at your Web Inspector timeline to see if those images are being loaded properly.

Comment: You are missing the `<html>` tag. You are using `type="JavaScript"` which is deprecated. The performance would improve once the images were loaded if it was down to this, is that the case or does it continue to run poorly once the images are fully loaded?

Comment: @eatsleeptrumpet : Does the performance stay low all the time while you are running your mousemove JS - or is it just at the beginning, meaning the images aren't being loaded to cache properly?

Comment: `var imageIndex = Math.floor(mloc.x / $(document).width() * images.length);`

Comment: @RafaelCichocki: Performance is consistently bad - I checked the inspector and it appears to be reloading the images every time they are called. I think jammypeach's suggestion above might help that, unless you have a different idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one big image Sprite and change the CSS background position instead of loading each image separately. This should improve the performance because you'd work with one image hance one HTTP request instead of 24 images and requests

You can find this useful: http://spritely.net/ especially if you want to do more complex animations.

And here is an example of animation with sprites: http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Dhirajkumar/DG_Slider/animated-backgound-image-sprite.htm

Comment: Thanks infinity - I've seen the "sprite sheet" technique recommended elsewhere and will probably give it a shot soon, but for this time I want to get my head around this JS preloading business.

Comment: do the one big sprites image thing, fixing the preloading is a waste of time when sprites resolves your issue and also improves loading time (one big file is only one request and the file should weight less than all the others summed), you should use preloading on other cases (like image galleries)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this,

best of both worlds (thanks to Shmiddty's suggestion of calculating image index):

```
var images = [],
    $stage = $('.stage'),
    oldIndex;

function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}

preload(
   "http://draves.org/pix/kdn/gen/acanthametra/big%20two%20spike%20star%20copy.small.jpg",
   "http://draves.org/pix/kdn/gen/ascidiae/orange%20ten%20branch%20copy.small.jpg", 
   "http://draves.org/pix/kdn/gen/ascidiae/six%20star%20copy.small.jpg");

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var mloc       = { x: event.pageX },
        imageIndex = Math.floor(mloc.x / $(document).width() * images.length);

    if (oldIndex !== 'undefined' && oldIndex !== imageIndex) {

        oldIndex = imageIndex;
        $stage.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[imageIndex].src + ')');
    }
});​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/rzY5L/2/

More of those preloaders could be found here (although outdated in some parts):
http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

**Update**
The flashing images appears to be related to .png handling (at least on Chrome it seems to flash when changing images). One solution is to create base64 versions of those images. Converter can be found here:
http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

**Base64 Fiddle (no flashing)**
http://jsfiddle.net/rzY5L/3/

Comment: This deals with the performance issue perfectly. One issue now is that  the mousemove event causes the image to constantly refresh because it is firing constantly instead of just when the mouse leaves a certain range. The result is a flashing effect. Do you think this would be fixed if I used some of my original code where I specified the ranges?

Comment: The flashing occurs only in WebKit browsers, it looks like.

Comment: Thanks - the logic makes total sense but Chrome and Safari still flash when the image does change. I loaded my implementation into a JSFiddle, would you mind looking at it? http://jsfiddle.net/7eAPk/3/

Comment: @eatsleeptrumpet Now that I see you're using static images to create animation kind of thingy, I recommend you to create image sprite, preload it and animate position, as someone already suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your help @micadelli, I went with the sprite sheet technique and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

from [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp) : *"For each  tag in an HTML document, an Image object is created."*

I understand you've been using [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/preloading-and-the-javascript-image-object/5214317). But it seems to me you just have one image object. Try creating a `new Image()` for every image you are trying to pre-load, i.e.

```
var image1 = new Image(); 
image1.src= 'img/1.png'; 

var image2 = new Image(); 
image2.src = 'img/2.png' 

...
```

Here's another [useful link](http://www.proglogic.com/learn/javascript/lesson10.php).

Comment: Thanks, this makes a good amount of sense as to how it would prevent further HTTP requests. I'll plug it in and follow up with the good news :)

Comment: The code is quite soggy, truth be told. How's about you DRY it out?

Answer (score 1):

a working code sample I use:

```
// preload images
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image()
        images[i].src = location.origin + "/PaymentManager" + preload.arguments[i]
    }
}
preload("/res/cards/visa.png","/res/cards/mastercard.png","/res/cards/amex.png","/images/loader.png");
```

it seems like you need to create a new Image object for every image.